# How to fix : No plugin found for prefix 'nexus-staging'

Tags: maven, nexus

Maven not able to find prefix 'nexus-staging', while executing command :-

mvn nexus-staging:release

I have cross verified that the plugin is also available at ".m2\repository\org\sonatype\plugins\nexus-staging-maven-plugin\1.6.8" location.

```xml
<plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.8</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                            <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                            <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The short form works only if configured for the groupId. Otherwise you need to write

```
org.sonatype.plugins:nexus-staging-maven-plugin:1.6.8:release
```